# Android universal image loader change referer to obtain images of URL

Tags: android, image, loader, universal, referer

I'm using Universal image Loader library to obtain images from Url. The problem is that I need to change referer to obtain these images. How can I change the url referer in Universal image loader library. Here is my part of code (it is placed in adapter)

```
ImageView imagenPersona = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgPersona);
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(activity));
imageLoader.displayImage(item.getUrlImagenPersona(), imagenPersona);
```

Thanks.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You have to write web service for this. (For example you can use curl with php) Send url param and referer param to your web service. This service will visit the url with referer.
Like this,

```
 $url   = $_POST["url"];  // Our image url adress
 $refer     = $url = $_POST["referer"]; // Our referer

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '$url ');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, '$refer ');
 $html = curl_exec($ch);
```

with this code you visited your image with your refer.

Comment: Thanks, but I need change the referer using Universal image loader library, How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the universalimageloader source code 
function  createConnection 
in file `com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader` 
function getStreamFromNetwork in file  `com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.HttpClientImageDownloader`
to set HttpURLConnection and httpRequest referer.

compile the java class file and replace the origin file in jar package